# The new pipeline experience (YAML) missing tracking and stats features

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, release, tracking

The new pipeline experience with the multi-stage pipeline feature is pretty neat, but is lacking some tracking and statistics features that are available using the classic release pipelines.
Are there any plans to support those with the YAML pipelines?

[Deployments are not reported to work items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjZuP.png)

[Deployment stats are not measured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX0Y4.png)

Comment: check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/features-timeline

Answer (score 0):

You can go to [Azure DevOps Feature Timeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/features-timeline) to check what Features are under development as Shayki Abramczyk mentioned.

For these features that are not available and not under development currently. You can always [submit user voices](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) for these features to Microsoft Development team.

You properly can find some similar features requests are already submitted. You can vote up on the existing feature requests(eg. [Link each stage of a YAML pipeline to work items](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1213434/link-each-stage-of-a-yaml-pipeline-to-work-items.html)), Or you can also submit new feature requests for your own.